# How do I connect to firebase emulator running in docker using Java?

Tags: java, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-tools

I managed to get a local version of firebase emulator running, using [this](https://github.com/seletskiy/firebase-emulator).
Everything seems to be running fine, and I'm even able to access the UI at http://localhost:4000. Here's a screenshot following `docker run`

[image]

Now, what I'd like to do is to connect to this locally emulated Firebase app, using a service account json file (Which can normally be downloaded from google cloud console). This is the code snippet using which I'm using to test.

```
public class GenericFcmTests {

    private static FirebaseOptions firebaseOptions;
    private static FirebaseApp firebaseApp;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GenericFcmTests.class.getName());

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() throws IOException {
        try (InputStream inputStream = Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseMessagingServiceImpl.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("serviceAccountKey.json"))) {
            firebaseOptions = FirebaseOptions.builder()
                    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(inputStream))
                    .build();
            firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(firebaseOptions);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Initialization failure: ", e);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetFireBaseInstance() throws FirebaseMessagingException {
        var messaging = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance(firebaseApp);
        var message = Message.builder()
                .setTopic("test-topic")
                .setNotification(Notification.builder().setTitle("Test tile").setBody("Test body").build())
                .build();
        var sent = messaging.send(message, true);
        assertFalse(StringUtils.isEmpty(sent));
        System.out.println(messaging);
    }
}
```

`serviceAccountKey.json` looks something like this:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "demo-project",
  "private_key_id": "abc",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\private key\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "firebase-adminsdk-asdfgt566@demo-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "clientId",
  "auth_uri": "http://localhost:9199",
  "token_uri": "http://localhost:9199/token"
}
```

Now, when I run the test, I get this error:

> com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingException: Unknown error while making a remote service call: Error getting access token for service account: Connection refused (Connection refused), iss: firebase-adminsdk-asdfgt566@demo-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com

How can I create a `serviceAccountKey` json file for local emulation access?

Comment: Have you referred to this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni doesn't this still require an actual service account credentials file from an existing project? That'd sort of defeat the purpose here.

Comment: Can you check with this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41874398/what-is-serviceaccountkey-json-referring-to-in-the-firebase-device-to-device-n)

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni I know how to generate a serviceAccountKey for an existing project, using the cloud console. My question explictily talks about serviceAccountKey for local emulation. I don't know how the link you referred to, would help me :)

Comment: You probably need to set the host in the firebase.json file, to run the emulator for localhost. You can refer to these [Stackobverflow link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66176947/run-google-firestore-emulator-with-docker-compose) and [Stackoveflow link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71072300/firebase-authentication-emulator-ui-in-docker-container-doesnt-work-on-localhos)

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni If you kindly go through the github link that I've referred to, in the question, you'll notice that `firebase.json` is configured, and to clarify something, running the emulator in localhost isn't an issue, but connecting to it using `Java` is! Also, I think the URL used when sending messages is hardcode in `FirebaseMessagingClientImpl` which is obviously going to fail when using local emulator for sending messages.

Comment: Can you check  1)if the server listens on the expected port (and on the expected host), 2) if the relevant Docker port is exposed, 3) if the client is aware of the proper host:port value so it can make a connection [similarly to this](https://github.com/seletskiy/firebase-emulator#client-side).

Comment: Additionally can you experiment with the values provided in the SA key file, note that FB Auth should listen on port 9099 and in the key JSON file we have:
  "auth_uri": "http://localhost:9199",
  "token_uri": "http://localhost:9199/token"